# Reverse Geocoding using Google maps API key on QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, google-maps-api, reverse-geocoding

I'm performing reverse geocode to obtain the coordinates of a big-data set (100k+ polygons) using QGIS. Using the "MMQGIS" plugin, I attempt to process my data with a personal google maps API key.

The process is strenuously slow and fragile and can be interrupted by literally anything; from a hitch in network connection to a simple pop-up on the PC screen, a slight movement of the mouse. these can all cause a QGIS software crash.

My fastest geocoding speed using G-maps API is 3336 points in 25 minutes. with my slowest at the rate of 3336 points in over 4 hours. At this time of writing, the most points geocoded points remain just over 15k+

Using the OSM/Nominatm option is a much slower process.

Please have you encountered such an issue working with spatial big data? Did you find a way around it?  Please freely share your help with me.

And yeah, my PC processor seems decent enough to; Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz   2.50 GHz